# How does Java's use-site variance compare to C#'s declaration site variance?

Tags: c#, java, generics, variance

My understand is that specifying variance for generics in C# happens at the type declaration level: when you're creating your generic type, you specify the variance for the type arguments. In Java, on the other hand, variance is specified where a generic is used: when you create a variable of some generic type, you specify how its type arguments can vary.

What are the pros and cons to each option?

Comment: A paper touching this question: http://cgi.di.uoa.gr/~smaragd/varj-ecoop12.pdf

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I am just going to answer the differences between declaration-site and use-site variance, since, while C# and Java generics differ in many other ways, those differences are mostly orthogonal to variance.

First off, if I remember correctly use-site variance is strictly more powerful than declaration-site variance (although at the cost of concision), or at least Java's wildcards are (which are actually more powerful than use-site variance). This increased power is particularly useful for languages in which stateful constructs are used heavily, such as C# and Java (but Scala much less so, especially since its standard lists are immutable). Consider `List<E>` (or `IList<E>`). Since it has methods for both adding E's and getting E's, it is invariant with respect to E, and so declaration-site variance cannot be used. However, with use-site variance you can just say `List<+Number>` to get the covariant subset of `List` and `List<-Number>` to get the contravariant subset of `List`. In a declaration-site language the designer of the library would have to make separate interfaces (or classes if you allow multiple inheritance of classes) for each subset and have `List` extend those interfaces. If the library designer does not do this (note that C#'s `IEnumerable` only does a small subset of the covariant portion of `IList`), then you're out of luck and you have to resort to the same hassles you have to do in a language without any sort of variance.

So that's the advantages of use-site inheritance over declaration-site inheritance. The advantage of declaration-site inheritance over use-site inheritance is basically concision for the user (provided the designer went through the effort of separating every class/interface into its covariant and contravariant portions). For something like `IEnumerable` or `Iterator`, it's nice not to have to specify covariance every single time you use the interface. Java made this especially annoying by using a lengthy syntax (except for bivariance for which Java's solution is basically ideal).

Of course, these two language features can coexist. For type parameters that are naturally covariant or contravariant (such as in `IEnumerable`/`Iterator`), declare so in the declaration. For type parameters that are naturally invariant (such as in `(I)List`), declare  what kind of variance you want each time you use it. Just don't specify a use-site variance for arguments with a declaration-site variance as that just makes things confusing.

There are other more detailed issues I haven't gone into (such as how wildcards are actually more powerful than use-site variance), but I hope this answers your question to your content. I'll admit I'm biased towards use-site variance, but I tried to portray the major advantages of both that have come up in my discussions with programmers and with language researchers.

Comment: Brilliant answer, thanks! Automatically splitting a type into co- and contra- variant portions using use-site variance wasn't something I'd thought of.

Comment: @munificent Glad you liked it. There's actually a paper coming out at PLDI this year which finds that 39% of use-site variances (in wildcards) could be made redundant if Java had declaration-site variance, but that also means that 61% of cases express uses inexpressible with declaration-site variance without breaking up classes and interfaces into co/contra/bi-variant components. Thought you might find those statistics interesting; I certainly did.

Comment: Whoa, that is surprising. I would have expected lower numbers but then since Java has no legacy of separating out mutability (even `Iterator<T>` has `remove()` after all), that probably makes sense. In fact, I wonder how many of those cases are specifically just because of `Iterator<T>`.

Answer (score 16):

Most people seem to prefer declaration-site variance, because it makes it easier for **users** of the library (while making it a bit harder for the library developer, although I would argue that the library developer has to think about variance regardless of where the variance is actually written.)

But keep in mind, that neither Java nor C# are examples of good language design.

While **Java** got variance right and working independently of the JVM because of compatible VM improvements in Java 5 and type-erasure, the use-site variance makes usage a bit cumbersome and the particular implementation of type-erasure has drawn well-deserved criticism.

**C#**'s model of declaration-site variance takes the burden away from the user of the library, but during their introduction of reified generics they basically built the variance rules into the their VM.
Even today they can't fully support co-/contravariance because of this mistake (and the non backward-compatible introduction of the reified collection classes has split the programmers into two camps).

This poses a difficult restriction on all languages targeting the CLR and is one reason why alternative programming languages are much more lively on the JVM although it seems that the CLR has "much nicer features".

Let's look at **Scala**: Scala is an fully object-oriented, functional hybrid running on the JVM.
They use type erasure like Java, but both the implementation of Generics and the (declaration-site) variance are easier to understand, more straightforward and powerful than Java's (or C#'s), because the VM doesn't impose rules on how variance has to work. The Scala compiler checks the variance notations and can reject unsound source code *at compile time* instead of throwing exceptions at runtime, while the resulting .class files can seamlessly be used from Java.

One disadvantage of declaration site variance is that it seems to make type inference harder in some cases.

At the same time Scala can use primitive types without boxing them in collections like in C# by using the `@specialized` annotation which tells the Scala compiler to generate one or multiple additional implementations of a class or method specialized to the requested primitive type.

Scala can also "almost" reify generics by using Manifests which allows them to retrieve the generic types at runtime like in C#.

Comment: This poses a difficult restriction on all languages targeting the CLR and is one reason why alternative programming languages are much more lively on the JVM although it seems that the CLR has "much nicer features" <- Sounds like nonsense to me. Implementing java style generics on .net shouldn't be hard. Just make them non generic in the .net sense and mark them in a way that your compiler understands.

Comment: And saying that alternative languages are much more lively on JVM is probably wrong too. There are lots of alternative languages on both platforms. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CLI_languages
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JVM_languages

Comment: Then you loose all interoperability with bytecode which uses generics. Looking at how much generics are used on C# lately, this is no option unless you plan to have a language with no interoperability at all. There are more languages and there is more language development at the JVM. Look at how Microsoft recently dropped support for IronRuby and IronPython.

Comment: The difference between alternative languages on CLR and JVM is that on the CLR most of them were some proof-of-concept projects which never took up speed or support. While the JVM has many of such experiments too, there is a substantial amount of languages actively developed outside of Oracle which actually have made inroads in adoption and user-share unlike on the CLR.

Comment: It may be that there are fewer languages, especially dynamic ones, on the CLR simply because C# is already a more terse and expressive language than Java. I can see myself using Scala or Groovy because I want lambdas, first-class functions, properties, and variance. On the CLR, C# already has all of those.

Answer (score 1):

**Disadvantages of Java style generics**

One consequence is that the java version only works with reference types(or boxed value-types) and not value-types. IMO that's the biggest disadvantage since it prevents high performance generics in a lot of scenarios and requires manual writing of specialized types.

It doesn't guarantee an invariant like "This list only contains objects of type x" and needs runtime checks at every getter. The generic type really exists.

When using reflection you can't ask an instance of a generic object which generic parameters it has.

**Advantages of Java style generics**

You get variance/can cast between different generic parameters.

Comment: C# has variance for type parameters too. My question was more about how use-site variance (Java) compares to declaration-site (C#) and not overall comparisons to generics on those platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Java: Use-site variance generics since Java 5. Broken covariant arrays with a different syntax since 1.0. No runtime type info of generics.

C#: Use-site variance generics since C# 2.0. Added declaration site variance in C# 4.0. Broken covariant arrays with a different syntax since 1.0 (identical issue to Java). "reified" generics meaning that type info isn't lost at compilation time.

Scala: Both use-site/declaration-site variance since early versions of the language (at least since 2008). Arrays are not a separate language feature, so you use the same generics syntax and type variance rules. Certain collections are implemented at the VM level with JVM arrays so you get equal or better runtime performance compared with Java code.

To elaborate on the C#/Java array type safety problem: You can cast a Dog[] to a Pet[] and add a Cat and trigger a runtime error that isn't caught at compilation time. Scala implemented this correctly.