# Creating a reverse collection on a Traversable

Tags: scala, covariance

I want to just reverse the items in this collection, so I decided to require that it be part of `Traversable`, and any of the subtypes for it, and have it return a Traversable, but I think I may need to use a variance on that also, but, at the moment I get a compiler error, using Scala 2.10.0-M5.

```
trait Polynomials {
    def coefficients[+A <: Traversable[T]](x:A):Traversable[A] =  x.foldLeft(Traversable[A]())((b,a) => a :: b)

}
```

These are the errors I am getting, and I am not certain what I did wrong.

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
']' expected but identifier found.  Polynomials.scala   line 4  Scala Problem
'=' expected but ']' found. Polynomials.scala   line 4  Scala Problem
illegal start of simple expression  Polynomials.scala   line 5  Scala Problem
```

Comment: Is this all the code in Polynomials.scala or are you omitting some code for the sake of berevity?

Comment: You need a self contained example. Type `T` is not defined anywhere. Furthermore, you cannot annotate a method's type parameter with a variance, so `+A` doesn't make any sense. A type in a method argument is always in contravariant position (you can call `def m(a: AnyRef)` with a `String` argument, and a return type is always in covariant position (you can treat the result of `def m() : String` as an `AnyRef`.

Comment: @EmilH - Actually, at the moment it is just this one function.  I will be adding more, but I got myself stuck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scala doesn't have [use-site variance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4231305/247533), so `+A` is not allowed in a method, only in a class.  It doesn't really make sense here anyway; I don't think you'll miss it.  Also, you need a `T` somewhere, either on the trait or on the method.  And `::` isn't defined on traversable, but a `List` is a traversable, so you can use one.  And you're actually returning a `Traversable[T]`, not a `Traversable[A]`.  So:

```
trait Polynomials {
  def coefficients[T, A <: Traversable[T]](x: A): Traversable[T] = 
    x.foldLeft(List[T]())((b,a) => a :: b)
}
```

But the `A <: Traversable[T]` isn't really buying you anything since subtyping gets you that anyway.  So shorter and simpler is

```
trait Polynomials {
  def coefficients[T](x: Traversable[T]): Traversable[T] = 
    x.foldLeft(List[T]())((b,a) => a :: b)
}
```