# What are the kinds of covariance in C#? (Or, covariance: by example)

Tags: c#, java, functional-programming, covariance

Covariance is (roughly) the ability to *mirror inheritance* of "simple" types in complex types that use them.
E.g. We can always treat an instance of `Cat` as an instance of `Animal`. A `ComplexType<Cat>` may be treated as a `ComplexType<Animal>`, if ComplexType is covariant.

I'm wondering: what are the "types" of covariance, and how do they relate to C# (are they supported?)
Code examples would be helpful.

For instance, one type is *return type covariance*, supported by Java, but not C#.

I'm hoping someone with functional programming chops can chime in, too!

Comment: I think you are confusing two different (but similar) concepts. One is called Covariance and the other is called Contravariance.

Comment: If you are looking for examples - almost all standart .Net collections are covariant.

Comment: @Nik correction. Almost all .net interfaces in the `System.Generic.Collections` namespace are covariant.

Comment: @Aron yes, thats what i meant, thx

Comment: There is a nice MSDN article on covariance an contravariance. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx) you go.

Comment: @Aron Care to expand on that? My understanding is that: 1. Covariance **translates** inheritance to complex types ( `Cat < Animal => IEnumerable<Cat> < IEnumerable<Animal>` ), and 2. Contravariance reverses the inheritance ( `Cat < Animal => Action<Cat> ** > ** Action<Animal>` ). And I'm only asking about **covariance** here.

Comment: I discuss [covariance and contravariance in Java](http://www.ii.uni.wroc.pl/~lukstafi/pmwiki/uploads/Java/java-lecture06.pdf) a bit, it is probably different form C# though.

Comment: You might want to read the long series of articles I wrote while designing the covariance / contravariance features added to C# 4.  These are in order from most recent to least recent, so start at the bottom. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/covariance+and+contravariance/default.aspx

Comment: @EricLippert Wow, that's a long list! I've read some of those articles. I'll have a go at them and update my answer below with the new findings :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Covariance and contravariance real world example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662369/covariance-and-contravariance-real-world-example)

Comment: @CristiDiaconescu I retract my statement, you understand covariance and contravariance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's what I can think of:

**Update**

After reading the constructive comments and the ton of articles pointed (and written) by Eric Lippert, I improved the answer:

- Updated the broken-ness of array covariance
- Added "pure" delegate variance
- Added more examples from the BCL
- Added links to articles that explain the concepts in-depth.
- Added a whole new section on higher-order function parameter covariance.

**Return type covariance**:

Available in Java (>= 5)<sup>[`[1]`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type)</sup> and C++<sup>[`[2]`](http://www.tolchz.net/?p=33)</sup>, not supported in C# (Eric Lippert explains [why not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9237056/11545) and [what you can do about it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5709191/11545)):

```
class B {
    B Clone();
}

class D: B {
    D Clone();
}
```

**Interface covariance**<sup>[`[3]`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/26/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-five-interface-variance.aspx)</sup> - supported in C#

The BCL defines the generic `IEnumerable` interface to be covariant:

```
IEnumerable<out T> {...}
```

Thus the following example is valid:

```
class Animal {}
class Cat : Animal {}

IEnumerable<Cat> cats = ...
IEnumerable<Animal> animals = cats;
```

Note that an `IEnumerable` is by definition "read-only" - you can't add elements to it.
Contrast that to the definition of `IList<T>` which can be modified e.g. using `.Add()`:

```
public interface IEnumerable<out T> : ...  //covariant - notice the 'out' keyword
public interface IList<T> : ...            //invariant
```

**Delegate covariance** by means of method groups <sup>[`[4]`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/19/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-three-member-group-conversion-variance.aspx)</sup> - supported in C#

```
class Animal {}
class Cat : Animal {}

class Prog {
    public delegate Animal AnimalHandler();

    public static Animal GetAnimal(){...}
    public static Cat GetCat(){...}

    AnimalHandler animalHandler = GetAnimal;
    AnimalHandler catHandler = GetCat;        //covariance

}
```

**"Pure" delegate covariance**<sup>[`[5 - pre-variance-release article]`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/22/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-four-real-delegate-variance.aspx)</sup> - supported in C#

The BCL definition of a delegate that takes no parameters and returns something is covariant:

```
public delegate TResult Func<out TResult>()
```

This allows the following:

```
Func<Cat> getCat = () => new Cat();
Func<Animal> getAnimal = getCat;
```

**Array covariance** - supported in C#, *in a broken way*<sup>[`[6]`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/17/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-two-array-covariance.aspx)</sup> <sup>[`[7]`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/09/24/why-is-covariance-of-value-typed-arrays-inconsistent.aspx)</sup>

```
string[] strArray = new[] {"aa", "bb"};

object[] objArray = strArray;    //covariance: so far, so good
//objArray really is an "alias" for strArray (or a pointer, if you wish)


//i can haz cat?
object cat == new Cat();         //a real cat would object to being... objectified.

//now assign it
objArray[1] = cat                //crash, boom, bang
                                 //throws ArrayTypeMismatchException
```

And finally - the surprising and somewhat mind-bending
**Delegate parameter covariance** (yes, that's *co*-variance) - for higher-order functions.<sup>[`[8]`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/24/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-five-higher-order-functions-hurt-my-brain.aspx)</sup>

The BCL definition of the delegate that takes one parameter and returns nothing is *contravariant*:

```
public delegate void Action<in T>(T obj)
```

Bear with me. Let's define a circus animal trainer - he can be told *how* to train an animal (by giving him an `Action` that works with that animal).

```
delegate void Trainer<out T>(Action<T> trainingAction);
```

We have the trainer definition, let's get a trainer and put him to work.

```
Trainer<Cat> catTrainer = (catAction) => catAction(new Cat());

Trainer<Animal> animalTrainer = catTrainer;  
// covariant: Animal > Cat => Trainer<Animal> > Trainer<Cat> 

//define a default training method
Action<Animal> trainAnimal = (animal) => 
   { 
   Console.WriteLine("Training " + animal.GetType().Name + " to ignore you... done!"); 
   };

//work it!
animalTrainer(trainAnimal);
```

The output proves that this works:

> Training Cat to ignore you... done!

In order to understand this, a joke is in order.

> A linguistics professor was lecturing to his class one day.
>   "In English," he said, "a double negative forms a positive.
>   However," he pointed out, "there is no language wherein a double positive can form a negative."
>
> A voice from the back of the room piped up, "Yeah, right."

What's *that* got to do with covariance?!

Let me attempt a back-of-the-napkin demonstration.

An `Action<T>` is contravariant, i.e. it "flips" the types' relationship:

```
A < B => Action<A> > Action<B> (1)
```

Change `A` and `B` above with `Action<A>` and `Action<B>` and get:

```
Action<A> < Action<B> => Action<Action<A>> > Action<Action<B>>  

or (flip both relationships)

Action<A> > Action<B> => Action<Action<A>> < Action<Action<B>> (2)
```

Put (1) and (2) together and we have:

```
,-------------(1)--------------.
 A < B => Action<A> > Action<B> => Action<Action<A>> < Action<Action<B>> (4)
         `-------------------------------(2)----------------------------'
```

But our `Trainer<T>` delegate is effectively an `Action<Action<T>>`:

```
Trainer<T> == Action<Action<T>> (3)
```

So we can rewrite (4) as:

```
A < B => ... => Trainer<A> < Trainer<B>
```

- which, by definition, means Trainer is covariant.

In short, applying `Action` *twice* we get contra-contra-variance, i.e. the relationship between types is flipped **twice** (see (4) ), so we're back to covariance.

Comment: Just a note about the array covariance: if you add a third line of `objArray[1] = new object();`, while legal at compile time will throw exceptions at runtime. In this sense, unlike the other examples, array covariance [is broken](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/17/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-two-array-covariance.aspx)

Comment: Good list. One small change I would make is to note that there are two kinds of delegate covariance as of C# 4. The kind you talk about I usually call *method group covariance*. Delegate covariance allows `delegate R D<R>(); ... D<Banana> db = ()=>new Banana(); D<Fruit> df = db;`

Answer (score 3):

This is best explained in terms of more generic, structural types. Consider:

1. Tuple types: (T1, T2),  a pair of types T1 and T2 (or more generally, n-tuples);
2. Function types: T1 -> T2,  a function with argument type T1 and result T2;
3. Mutable types: Mut(T),  a mutable variable holding a T.

Tuples are covariant in both their component types, i.e. (T1, T2) < (U1, U2) iff T1 < U1 and T2 < U2 (where '<' means is-subtype-of).

Functions are covariant in their result and contravariant in their argument, i.e. (T1 -> T2) < (U1 -> U2) iff U1 < T1 and T2 < U2.

Mutable types are invariant, i.e. Mut(T) < Mut(U) only iff T = U.

All these rules are the most general correct subtyping rules.

Now, an object or interface type like you know it from mainstream languages can be interpreted as a fancy form of tuple containing its methods as functions, among other things. For example, the interface

```
interface C<T, U, V> {
  T f(U, U)
  Int g(U)
  Mut(V) x
}
```

essentially represents the type

```
C(T, U, V) = ((U, U) -> T, U -> Int, Mut(V))
```

where f, g, and x correspond to the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd component of the tuple, respectively.

It follows from the rules above that C(T, U, V) < C(T', U', V') iff T < T' and U' < U and V = V'. That means that the generic type C is covariant in T, contravariant in U and invariant in V.

Another example:

```
interface D<T> {
  Int f(T)
  T g(Int)
}
```

is

```
D(T) = (T -> Int, Int -> T)
```

Here, D(T) < D(T') only if T < T' and T' < T. In general, that can only be the case if T = T', so D actually is invariant in T.

There also is a fourth case, sometimes called "bivariance", which means both co- and contravariant at the same time. For example,

```
interface E<T> { Int f(Int) }
```

is bivariant in T, because it is not actually used.

Answer (score 1):

Java employs the concept of *use-site variance* for generic types: the needed variance is specified at each use site. This is why Java programmers are required to be familiar with the so-called PECS rule. Yes, it is unwieldy and has already received plenty of criticism.

Comment: +1 Interesting. This [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4231305/11545) and the linked [article](http://cgi.di.uoa.gr/~smaragd/varj-ecoop12.pdf) give a description of the difference between use-site variance (Java) and declaration-site variance (C#).

Comment: Thanks for the link, Cristi, that's one of the best SO answers overall!